Unknown or hidden generator under exponentiation of singular finite matrices digital signature attempt.
My question is, in the following signature scheme, if there's any algebraic attack to apply to break it. I ask here in math.se as it's mostly algebraic, and has raised no interest in crypto.se
$\mathcal{M}\subset Mat(n,p)$ is the set of singular $n\times n$ square matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and rank $n-1$. The following equality defines the signature scheme:
$G\cdot A^{kh}\cdot A^{qh}=G\cdot A^c$ $(1)$
Where, $G,A\in \mathcal{M}$ are singular non commuting generator matrices of order $o=p^{n-1}-1$. $k$, $c$, $q$ and $h$ are exponents inside the limits of $o$. $h$ is the number to sign. $S=A^q$ is the signature.
The private and public information of the signer is:
Private: $\left< G,A,k,c\right>$
Public: $\left<G\cdot A^k, G\cdot A^c\right>$
To find the signature we use a calculation on the exponents, i.e., in $\mathbb{Z}_o$ as follows:
$q\equiv c/h-k\pmod{o}$, $S=A^q$
To check for a valid signature the equality $(1)$ must hold using $S=A^q$.
The question is: There is any obvious algebraic attack on this construction? Literature on the subject will be appreciated as well.
Notes:
There's check.py, a sagemath implementation of the signing process.
$A^q$ commutes with some $A^s$, that can be provided to make the signature more compact.
